# Consensus Mechanism Comparison

Tags: multiversx

Hypothetically, if you had to create a way to objectively review, rate and compare consensus algorithms, what properties would you look at? What properties would you evaluate? Would you give the properties different weights? For example, "How easy is it to become part of the network (consensus group)?", Security (how do you even define security?), Network share necessary for takeover, does it allow for scalability, does it have any central point of failures, ...? Would you include the underlying economics? Because Bitcoin's economics will eventually lead to insane transaction fees, even more so than the current ones. Would you give the different criterias different weights? If yes, what would be more important and what less?

I would be insanely grateful for getting a few different answers and opinions